# How do I remove this piece when the other side is obstructed?

Tags: disassembly, piece-usage

I bought and constructed the Millenium Falcon 75192.

Now, I'm breaking it apart for storage. I just don't know how to remove the black piece below (the same as the alone one but in the structure) without applying an insane pressure that I fear might destroy the piece. Usually I just use other pieces to push it out from behind, but in this case, the backside is obstructed by another piece behind, and every piece is stuck because of that one piece I can't remove.

[image]

Edit: I forgot to mention that I tried using the thin part of the orange piece to unclip bricks, but I just can't use it in this case: it simply doesn't work as it's too thick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, half a pin is still present on the back side, so it isn't that bad. Things I would try:

1. Wiggle and pull out the part in question as-is, since pin slots are parallel to the part itself it could be possible to pull out the part ever slightly to make the rest of the job easy. If you find it hard to grab/wiggle the part try attaching something to an available pin hole - like a pin and some connector, to make some sort of lever.
2. Use some long and narrow non-LEGO item and push the part from the back. Since you'd be pushing against a back wall of a pin hole there won't be much damage visible even if you use brute force with sharp object like needle. And since this a Technic element, which tend to be made of a slightly harder plastic than usual bricks, there is low chance of damaging it even with sharp object.
3. As least favorite option I'd try using something flat and sharp between L-shaped brick and element you wish to remove. While it is possible to complete this action without damaging any of bricks this option has the highest chance of leaving some marks.

Comment: The needle idea gave me a better option: using a wooden toothpick. I could put enough pressure and it's the toothpick that was half destroyed afterwards, not the piece. So thank you a lot for leading me there!